# Do all elements of the domain have to map to a value in the co-domain for a function to be invertible?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Theorem: A function is invertible if and only if it is bijective

I understand this theorem, but one thing I feel is missing is that all elements in the domain have to map to some element in the co-domain. I do not feel like this theorem captures that. Am I right to say that all elements of the domain have to map to an element in the co-domain? If so, how does the theorem enforce this? It seems to me that the theorem enforces all the elements in the co-domain to be mapped to by some element in the domain - a unique one in particular - but not that all elements of the domain have to map to an element in the co-domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default (in mathematics) all functions are [total functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function) unless specifically identified as [partial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).  This means a function is a relation for every element of its domain.

In some areas of computability theory, functions are partial by default.  For instance, when discussing [semidecidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)#Semidecidability), the subject matter is partial functions.